# Is there any description of linux boot procedure at source level?

Tags: linux, bootstrapping

I'd like to study C and assembly codes related to bootstrapping. I have tried to google with many keyword, but most webpages contain overview of bootstrapping. Of course, because I'm poor at english, I couldn't find appropriate keyword to the desired results. I mean I want webpages or books that describe what the following files do.

```
usr/src/linux-3.2.28/arch/x86/boot/header.S  
usr/src/linux-3.2.28/arch/x86/boot/main.c  
usr/src/linux-3.2.28/arch/x86/boot/pm.c  
usr/src/linux-3.2.28/arch/x86/boot/pmjump.S  
usr/src/linux-3.2.28/arch/x86/boot/compressed/head_32.S
arch/x86/boot/kernel/head_32.S  
usr/src/linux-3.2.28/arch/x86/boot/compressed/misc.c 
init/main.c
```

Any webpage?

Comment: There is the ancient http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux-i386-Boot-Code-HOWTO/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the search ['the kernel boot process'](http://google.com/search?q=the+kernel+boot+process) and was lead to [*"Inside the Linux boot process"* on IBM developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linuxboot/) which has this diagram:

[image: boot flow diagram]

You should read through that article to get a nice overview of the boot process.

Comment: @inherithandle : What _DO_ you actually want? An line-by-line explanation of the source code? If so, pay for consulting.

Comment: Right. But I'd like free explanation.